# Script to export the final row of a spreadsheet as a text file, everytime it is updated

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'd like to create a Google script that will run whenever a particular Google Sheet is updated, exporting the new row to a new text file. The text file would be named after the first cell in the row, and would be saved in a Google Drive folder.

Is this even possible with a script? It seems like it should be but I don't know where to start.

Thanks all,
J

Comment: Use the onEdit() trigger, to save the change in Script Properties.
Use another trigger every minute (manually install a trigger) to check Script Properties to create a new text file. (these functions should be seperated, because of the restricted permissions on onEdit())

Comment: the onEdit is called a simple trigger and has restrictions, see: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/#restrictions

you should create another function that does the work of creating a new text file (this is not a simple trigger, and you can let GAS run this one every minute to check updates)

Answer (score 1):

This is a very basic version of what you want. It should get you started.

```
// You will need to set up an installable onEdit trigger through Resources
// on the Script Editor menu.
//Creates a comma separated text file in root of google drive in
// folder named 'Test File' the must be created in root.
function onEdit(e) {
     var activeSheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
     var sheetName=activeSheet.getName()//get the active sheet name
if(sheetName == "Sheet1") {// only if sheet name is Sheet1
  var thisRow = e.range.getRow();//get the row number of edited row
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var s = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");//the sheet name
  var lc = s.getLastColumn() // last col with data
  var range = s.getRange(thisRow,1,1,lc);//the entire edited row
  var rowvalues = range.getValues();//get row values

  var str=rowvalues.join(" ") // converts array to string
  var name = rowvalues[0][0] // gets the col A value of edited row to name file
  var folder='Test File'// file in root folder to put file in
  var dir = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(folder).next();
  var file = dir.createFile(name, str,'text/plain');//create file
 }}
```